# Expo RN: Detach vs Eject

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

I currently have an app built in React Native using Expo (create-react-native-app) that needs some native code. As I understand one has two options for dropping down to pure react native, ejecting and detaching. Seeing that I have already have used a fair amount Expo API's up until this point, I must detach to ExpoKit. Is my understanding correct that if I purely eject (as opposed to detaching to ExpoKit) the current Expo tools I have used wont work?

Appreciate any feedback!

Comment: Did you ever find out the answer to this? I have the same question.

Comment: Hey @Joe. Here is what I learned from my 'ejecting' experience. In a nutshell, ejecting (npm run eject) will completely remove Expo from your project, and every Expo tool/service you use will need to be replaced buy a native solution (that requires manual linking or react-native link etc). Detaching (exp detach) will allow you to keep using the Expo API's (but now through ExpoKit) and your project will remain pointed to Expo's react-native fork, but you will have your separate projects to add native code in. But in the end I made a pure RN project and replaced all Expo with native libraries

Comment: Any other workaround ideas? Struggling with a similar issue, but not the same one.

Comment: @Silmarilos what's the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 5):

Seems that there is no difference between Expo Eject and Expo Detach - eject is just the new name used...

See https://forums.expo.io/t/ejecting-vs-detaching-to-expokit/16295/2