# What is the difference between expo detach and expo eject?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am new to expo and I have a confusion whether expo project will allow me to use the various RN libraries available on GitHub. I have read that we need to detach expo in order to use external libraries. If we do so, are we still able to use expo's core features like push notifications?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54869383/5532513

Answer (score 0):

In order to use libraries that require native capabilities that are not supported  by default by RN, you would need **linking**

Now, the project structure provided by expo does not support linking, so you should convert your project the default project structure that you would normally get if you create your project using this command:

```
> react-native init <project-name>
```

This conversion is what's called **ejecting from expo**

In case that your project has a dependency on one of the core features supported by expo like push notifications, you will be asked during this **"conversion aka eject"** process whether you want to eject to **expo kit**, in this case, your code that's dependent on expo features would work normally after conversion, otherwise your code would break.